# Flyway always execute repeatable migrations

Tags: sql, database-migration, flyway

Is it possible to execute repeatable migrations in flyway even when the checksum is the same? The problem I am facing is having a view which extends another table with additional rows and the view doesn't get updated automatically.

An example here:

`R__person_view.sql`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW person_view AS 
    SELECT p.*, e.name FROM person p, entity e
    WHERE /* not relevant here ... */;
```

If this migration is executed at first it will work fine. If I add another migration, where I modify the table `person`, the changes are not adapted, because the view migration checksum did not change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, from Flyway 6.3.0 it has been possible to have repeatable migrations run each time [using the timestamp placeholder](https://flywaydb.org/blog/flyway-timestampsAndRepeatables) in a comment, ensuring that Flyway sees this as being changed afresh each time. For example:

```
R__UtilityProcedures.sql
-- ${flyway:timestamp}
create or replace procedure my_important_proc
```

Comment: It can fail on after migration validation step, so it's better to introduce your own unique key-value  pair that can be used everywhere using custom placeholders `placeholders.put("ALWAYS_RUN_REPEATABLE", String.valueOf(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()))`